# iTextSharp - calculating phrase/paragraph height before adding to column

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am creating PDF work orders that have a varying amount of items and notes. I am using `ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn(phrase, x, y, x2, y2, height, alignment)` to add text to a single column.

I can get the ColumnText.YLine value, but only *after* applying it to the ColumnText object with the `Go()` method.

What I want to do is to either pre-calculate the final YLine value or undo the adding of a phrase if the YLine is past mjy bottom threshold so I can manually add another page and continue. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. It's even documented in chapter 3 of my book: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C03

Answer (score 6):

As indicated in the comment I posted earlier, the answer to your question is yes. [MovieColumns3](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=66) shows you how to do it:

Instead of using a static `ColumnText` method, you need to create a `ColumnText` object and use the `setSimpleColumn()` method on that object. You can work in *text mode* adding `Phrase` objects with the `addText()` method, or in *composite mode* adding any type of `Element` using the `addElement()` method.

Normally, you'd then invoke the `go()` method to render those elements, but that's the whole point of your question: before you render any element, you want to know of the element fits. That can be done to use the `go()` method in simulation mode: `go(true)`. This will *pretend* to add the content, but won't render anything. You can get the Y position using the `getYLine()` method and check if all the content was added using the `hasMoreText()` method.

It's important to understand that the `go()` method (partially) *consumes* the content of the `ColumnText` object. Once you decide to add the content for real (that is: not in simulation mode) be it on the current page or the next page, you need to discard all remaining content from the `ColumnText` object and add it anew.

You'll find a more detailed explanation in my [book](http://itextpdf.com/book) and if you don't recognize the methods in the example because it's written in Java, please compare with the [C# port](http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C03) of the example.